# Assets Recompilation suddenly fails Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, asset-pipeline

If I try to deploy my application to heroku I get the following mistake during the assets precompilation:

#### Error

```
I, [2014-11-06T18:09:07.080717 #4262]  INFO -- : Writing /tmp/build_9f05208fefb8f884aa9795eaa1e68121/public/assets/application-d5c20e948f57d1e1a172809bf41b14e8.js
       rake aborted!
       ArgumentError: wrong number of arguments (2 for 1)
       (in /tmp/build_9f05208fefb8f884aa9795eaa1e68121/app/assets/stylesheets/load_bootstrap.css.scss)
       /tmp/build_9f05208fefb8f884aa9795eaa1e68121/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sass-3.4.7/lib/sass/importers/filesystem.rb:14:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_9f05208fefb8f884aa9795eaa1e68121/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/sass_importer.rb:11:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_9f05208fefb8f884aa9795eaa1e68121/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/compass-rails-2.0.1/lib/compass-rails/patches/sass_importer.rb:12:in `new'
       /tmp/build_9f05208fefb8f884aa9795eaa1e68121/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/compass-rails-2.0.1/lib/compass-rails/patches/sass_importer.rb:12:in `block in evaluate'
       /tmp/build_9f05208fefb8f884aa9795eaa1e68121/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/compass-rails-2.0.1/lib/compass-rails/patches/sass_importer.rb:12:in `map'
       /tmp/build_9f05208fefb8f884aa9795eaa1e68121/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/compass-rails-2.0.1/lib/compass-rails/patches/sass_importer.rb:12:in `evaluate'
       /tmp/build_9f05208fefb8f884aa9795eaa1e68121/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/tilt-1.4.1/lib/tilt/template.rb:103:in `render'
       /tmp/build_9f05208fefb8f884aa9795eaa1e68121/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:197:in `block in evaluate'
       /tmp/build_9f05208fefb8f884aa9795eaa1e68121/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `each'
       /tmp/build_9f05208fefb8f884aa9795eaa1e68121/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/context.rb:194:in `evaluate'
       /tmp/build_9f05208fefb8f884aa9795eaa1e68121/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:12:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_9f05208fefb8f884aa9795eaa1e68121/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `new'
       /tmp/build_9f05208fefb8f884aa9795eaa1e68121/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `block in build_asset'
       /tmp/build_9f05208fefb8f884aa9795eaa1e68121/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:395:in `circular_call_protection'
       /tmp/build_9f05208fefb8f884aa9795eaa1e68121/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:373:in `build_asset'
       /tmp/build_9f05208fefb8f884aa9795eaa1e68121/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
       /tmp/build_9f05208fefb8f884aa9795eaa1e68121/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
       /tmp/build_9f05208fefb8f884aa9795eaa1e68121/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
       /tmp/build_9f05208fefb8f884aa9795eaa1e68121/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_9f05208fefb8f884aa9795eaa1e68121/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_9f05208fefb8f884aa9795eaa1e68121/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:111:in `block in resolve_dependencies'
       /tmp/build_9f05208fefb8f884aa9795eaa1e68121/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:105:in `each'
       /tmp/build_9f05208fefb8f884aa9795eaa1e68121/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:105:in `resolve_dependencies'
       /tmp/build_9f05208fefb8f884aa9795eaa1e68121/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:97:in `build_required_assets'
       /tmp/build_9f05208fefb8f884aa9795eaa1e68121/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/processed_asset.rb:16:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_9f05208fefb8f884aa9795eaa1e68121/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `new'
       /tmp/build_9f05208fefb8f884aa9795eaa1e68121/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:374:in `block in build_asset'
       /tmp/build_9f05208fefb8f884aa9795eaa1e68121/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:395:in `circular_call_protection'
       /tmp/build_9f05208fefb8f884aa9795eaa1e68121/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:373:in `build_asset'
       /tmp/build_9f05208fefb8f884aa9795eaa1e68121/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
       /tmp/build_9f05208fefb8f884aa9795eaa1e68121/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
       /tmp/build_9f05208fefb8f884aa9795eaa1e68121/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
       /tmp/build_9f05208fefb8f884aa9795eaa1e68121/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_9f05208fefb8f884aa9795eaa1e68121/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_9f05208fefb8f884aa9795eaa1e68121/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/bundled_asset.rb:16:in `initialize'
       /tmp/build_9f05208fefb8f884aa9795eaa1e68121/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `new'
       /tmp/build_9f05208fefb8f884aa9795eaa1e68121/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:377:in `build_asset'
       /tmp/build_9f05208fefb8f884aa9795eaa1e68121/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:94:in `block in build_asset'
       /tmp/build_9f05208fefb8f884aa9795eaa1e68121/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/caching.rb:58:in `cache_asset'
       /tmp/build_9f05208fefb8f884aa9795eaa1e68121/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:93:in `build_asset'
       /tmp/build_9f05208fefb8f884aa9795eaa1e68121/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/base.rb:287:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_9f05208fefb8f884aa9795eaa1e68121/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/index.rb:61:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_9f05208fefb8f884aa9795eaa1e68121/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:211:in `block in find_asset'
       /tmp/build_9f05208fefb8f884aa9795eaa1e68121/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:257:in `benchmark'
       /tmp/build_9f05208fefb8f884aa9795eaa1e68121/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:210:in `find_asset'
       /tmp/build_9f05208fefb8f884aa9795eaa1e68121/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:119:in `block in compile'
       /tmp/build_9f05208fefb8f884aa9795eaa1e68121/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `each'
       /tmp/build_9f05208fefb8f884aa9795eaa1e68121/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/sprockets/manifest.rb:118:in `compile'
       /tmp/build_9f05208fefb8f884aa9795eaa1e68121/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:60:in `block (3 levels) in define'
       /tmp/build_9f05208fefb8f884aa9795eaa1e68121/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-2.12.3/lib/rake/sprocketstask.rb:146:in `with_logger'
       /tmp/build_9f05208fefb8f884aa9795eaa1e68121/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/sprockets-rails-2.0.1/lib/sprockets/rails/task.rb:59:in `block (2 levels) in define'
       Tasks: TOP => assets:precompile
       (See full trace by running task with --trace)
 !
 !     Precompiling assets failed.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Multipack app
```

#### The load_bootstrap file

```
@import 'bootstrap-sprockets';
@import "bootstrap";
```

#### My Gemfile

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby "2.1.3"
gem 'rails'

gem 'pg'

gem 'sass-rails'
gem "sprockets"
gem 'uglifier'

gem 'coffee-rails'

gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'turbolinks'
gem 'jbuilder'
gem 'devise'
gem 'haml-rails'
gem 'gravatar-ultimate'
gem 'remotipart'
gem 'less-rails' #Sprockets (what Rails 3.1 uses for its asset pipeline) supports LESS
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'formtastic'
gem 'formtastic-bootstrap'

gem 'paperclip'
gem 'fog'
gem 'carrierwave'
gem 'carrierwave_direct'


gem 'sidekiq'
gem 'sinatra', require: false
gem 'slim'


gem 'aws-sdk'
gem 'cancancan'
gem 'acts-as-taggable-on'
gem 'acts_as_commentable'
gem 'will_paginate'
gem 'handles_sortable_columns'
gem 'i18n-tasks'

gem 'streamio-ffmpeg', :git => 'git://github.com/hartator/streamio-ffmpeg.git', :ref => 'a1c59ca'
gem 'chosen-rails'
gem 'jquery-tokeninput-rails'


group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails'
  gem 'faker'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails'
  gem 'shoulda-matchers'
  gem 'rack-mini-profiler'
end

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', require: false
end


group :development do
  # Capistrano deployment
  gem 'capistrano'
  gem 'capistrano-bundler'
  gem 'capistrano-rails'
  gem 'capistrano-rvm'
end

group :production do
  gem 'therubyracer'
end
```

Any ideas where this could come from?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The contents of Gemfile.lock would be more useful for debugging than just the Gemfile.

Comment: Sure, my Gemfile.lock can be seen here: https://gist.github.com/sebastianzillessen/fedb5c3b41a2d763879b